# Does there exist pcb laminates with aluminium layers instead of copper

Tags: pcb-fabrication

Is there a product that acts like normal copper clad laminate, but the conductive layer is aluminum?
I would like to try using one of these due to technical limitations in a laser system we have.

To my understanding the oxidation of the aluminum will also be a problem but is there a way to circumvent this this? Can it be tinned somehow so the oxidation does not occur? How do you handle this if at all?

Comment: Not free of copper, but maybe https://www.4pcb.com/Aluminum-Clad-Special.html ?

Comment: If you don't want "aluminum core for heatsink", then the search term is "aluminum trace pcb"

Comment: @BenVoigt aah yes make that an answer.

Comment: Why would you want to? Aluminum is a has worse thermal characteristics than copper and also has issues with galvanic corrosion and oxidation. It would be hard to solder to.

Comment: @VoltageSpike because i want to reduce the time it takes to prepare students to operate machinery. The characteristics don't really matter these are almost always throwaway boards anyway

Comment: You can machine copper, if you want students to be able to make a PCB use a copper clad laminate. I built many PCB's as a student and it was helpful. LPKF makes a good machine that is usable by a student: https://www.lpkf.com/en/industries-technologies/research-in-house-pcb-prototyping/products/lpkf-protomat-e44

Comment: If you did manufacture an 'aluminum' pcb, you could do so, you would not be able to easily attach components to said PCB

Comment: @VoltageSpike how to deal with that was my second question.

Comment: To expand on what @VoltageSpike just said, since you might not be aware: Soldering to aluminum requires special (read: expensive) zinc-based solders and aggressive (read: dangerous and hard to work with) fluxes. And even then it's really difficult to get a good joint.

Comment: There are really good reasons why PCB's use copper and not aluminum.

Comment: @Hearth yes i understand that. But i would like to evaluate the feasibility since the other advantages would be so penomenally good

Comment: @joojaa I'm having a hard time seeing *any* advantages. You just say "due to technical limitations". Even the fact that aluminum is cheaper than copper is outweighed by the fact that aluminum-clad laminate is not a standard thing dozens of companies make.

Comment: @joojaa what advantages?

Comment: @Hearth the problem is that copper reflects the laser nearly completely. while aluminium is not much of a problem. I dont have budget for a UV laser at the moment.

Comment: @joojaa What laser?

Comment: @Hearth i dont think thats essential to the question. But yes i have a small 60'000€ lasercutter that can cut most metals, and composites but not really even a thin layer of copper.

Comment: @joojaa You've never mentioned a laser cutter before in this question. It helps a *lot* to understand *why* you want what you want.

Comment: This is either a mechanical or chemical question -- suggest closing or moving to another stack.  Or, I suppose there isn't a metallurgy stack... but that's just metallic chemistry, eh?

Comment: @TimWilliams ok sure i can remove the part of how to deal with the surface, but its really hard to get a no as an answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are no manufacturer that offer such option. But, many are willing to work with their customers to find a solution. If not, your best chance is probably using a CNC (LPKF style) and making your own PCB.

Comment: Yeah thats what we do. But if we could use non copper PCB's we could make 2 sided boards in 2-3 minutes. And  if needed do a mask on top with say spraying once dry, use same laser for 10 seconds per side to take the mask off areas where we dont need it. No tool changes, no tool calibration, no dirlling, no holding. Punch board against pins, flip push against pins. If you need mask repeat after spraying.

Comment: So you are searching for a supplier of bare PCB board to increase your prod efficiency? I'm not the right person to answer that, sorry!

Comment: No, not really. Time is not of essence. But teching 120 a students to operate a pcb milling machine is a bit complicated. And results in lots of broken milling heads and oher problems. The laser operation is much much easier to teach, since essentially there's only 2 things to consider. So i would save 2 months of contact teaching.

Comment: Although the speed does give the bonus that you can process a class of 40 students of in a days.

Comment: @joojaa The way my school handled this is having a handful of students trained on the milling machine and paying them (as student employees) to operate the machine for all the other students in the department, who would just send Gerber files like you would any other fab.

Comment: @Hearth yes thats whet we do, but we need to increase agency of students. So its this or etching. I would prefer this.

Comment: @joojaa *But if we could use non copper PCB's we could make 2 sided boards in 2-3 minutes.* The toughest part will be process quality and cleanliness needed for plated-through holes, or for any other electrochemical treatment. Cutting out the traces is basically the least of a problem. You can electrochemically plate copper with aluminum, and use the laser on that. The aluminum plasma acts like a light absorber and heats up the underlying copper. The process works, but I'm really not understanding what you're trying to do. PCB milling machines are simple.

Comment: @joojaa And yes, you can solder to aluminum. Look for youtube videos about that. No problem once you get the hang of it. Any company that makes copper-clad laminate can manufacture a custom run of aluminum-clad laminate. After laser-etching you'll need to put the boards into a reducing wash to get rid of the oxide, then in an inert atmosphere move it to a solder plating tank. The aqueous solutions need to have some additives that will prevent dissolved oxygen or dissociated OH ions from binding to aluminum. Bare pure aluminum is highly reactive.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica yes that's one of the ideas i was going to test. The milled board has same trough hole problem though.  As for pcb milling machines being simple, sure for you or me. But I am not teaching engineering students here so trust me this is easier.

Comment: @joojaa Handling aluminum in an unpassivated "bare metal" state is hard. You'd do much better changing the laser to something that can deal with Cu rather than depending on aluminum. If you asked me to design such a process, I'd go with aluminum plating on top of copper, use it only for laser cutting, and then strip it off. Laser doesn't mind the thin oxide layer. Way easier than trying to tin-coat it reliably. Best not to have any alu in finished product,

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica write that as an answer. Yeah i know, i could get a UV laser but i would need to wait another 3 years i need to live with what i have for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is one process.  It was developed for superconducting applications at mK temperatures, if that gives you any idea of how esoteric it is.

[Aluminum Trace Printed Circuit Board: Case Study | Omni Circuit Boards](https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/186189/file-237534923-pdf/Omni-Circuit-Boards-Aluminium-on-Aluminium-%C6%92.pdf)

It's not even apparent whether they can make vias and multilayer boards, or soldered joints; though they do show soldering on their website (possibly by Cu interface layer?).  Wire bonding I suppose is fine, but that's not much help if you aren't using superconducting chips.

It sounds like you may need a development team of a few dozen, from diverse backgrounds, to reproduce their process.  The PCB mills are probably the better solution for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 0):

You can get copper on aluminum, which is more of a common process because of LED lighting.  https://www.pcbway.com/pcb_prototype/General_introduction_of_Aluminum_PCB.html

You can machine copper, I did that as a student https://www.lpkf.com/en/industries-technologies/research-in-house-pcb-prototyping/products/lpkf-protomat-e44

Comment: Yes, we have several milling machines. But the thing is i need to process 120 students in a semester that have no engineering background.

Comment: You can also get small bits here: https://www.precisebits.com/applications/pcbtools.htm

Comment: I know where to get bits, i do buy more of them nearly every second week

Comment: @joojaa A much better time spent would be on automating the PCB milling production line. Load the boards on the left, get milled boards on the right, machines in-between. Everything under covers, no touching of any mechanical parts during a production run. Tool changers, exhaust, etc. That's the only feasible way to do it, given how hard it is to dispose of plating waste products. Large up front investment for automating the line, then it'll be cheap to run. Students should upload Gerbers to a control computer and that's where their involvement (and yours) mostly should end I think.

Comment: @joojaa Before doing any plating or other aqueous chemistry with metals - read up on what it takes to dispose of the stuff. It may be more trouble than is worth. Also talk to someone has plating research lab background - they'll actually know how feasible it'd be in your circumstances. A lot of that stuff is easy on paper but surprisingly annoying in reality.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica yes i understand all this, this is what we do, but i need to increase the agency of the students in question, we could order boards too that's not exactly a problem.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica yes we do copper, silver and gold plating regularly.